# Vertical Alignment doesn't work XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, grid, alignment, center

How do I center a Windows Store app so that it is in the middle of the screen, including all its content, using XAML/C#?

I tried this:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

But it seems that the `vertical alignment` doesn't work and the grid is staying at the top of the screen.

**EDIT:** I want the red section to be in the center of the screen:

[image]

```
 <Grid RequestedTheme="Light" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Name="FadeImageStoryboard">
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" 
                                 To="1" 
                                 Duration="0:0:0.7"
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <Image Source="assets/113h.jpg" Stretch="Fill"  x:Name="BackgroundImage" RequestedTheme="Light" Margin="0,-10,0,10" />
        <Button  x:Name="backButton" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                        Margin="23,45,0,0" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                        AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button" Click="backButton_Click"/>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Container">
            <Grid    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"> 
                <TextBox Margin="363,172,368,308" PlaceholderText="Last Name" BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="LastName"/>                  

                <Button Content="Sign-Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,417,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Register_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Having trouble to visualize your problem. Maybe share a quick and dirty mock up image of what you get versus what you want and it would be easier to translate that to the xaml you need.

Comment: @ChrisW. That's what I see. I want that the red will be in the center  of the screen http://postimg.org/image/vdr8v5wbx/

Comment: It looks to me like you have more going on in that layout that would keep it from working the way you would expect, like there's another row or something pushing that piece of your content up there. Maybe show some more xaml?

Comment: *All* the XAML would be nice, since `Grid` will be positioned according to its parent container.

Comment: Add some xaml to your question

Comment: @ChrisW Just Aded my code, can you review it pleas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Grid` is wrapped in a `StackPanel`. That means its centering *within the stack panel*. Which, given how `StackPanel` works, doesn't really make much sense anyways.

Take the `Grid` out (make it a child of the root `Grid`) and the centering will work as you expect.

```
 <Grid RequestedTheme="Light" Loaded="Grid_Loaded" Background="{ThemeResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   ...
   //No StackPanel!
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"> 
        <TextBox Margin="363,172,368,308" PlaceholderText="Last Name" BorderBrush="#FF755CB0" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.9" x:Name="LastName"/>      
        <Button Content="Sign-Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="360,417,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="257" Height="50" Background="#FF235085" BorderBrush="#FF6749AC" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="White" Opacity="0.9" RequestedTheme="Light" Click="Register_Click"/>
    </Grid>
    ....
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Tal Sure, added it in.